# How can I override the "instanceof" on an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: typescript, three.js, webgl

I'm working on an application using threejs and I simply need to draw a filled polygon given its vertices. So I'm starting with a square, and got it working independently of my project just fine.

The problem comes when I implement the geometry into my main project, which has third party libraries using threejs as well. A library runs `array.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer` which for some reason returns false even when I've verified that it returns true after I create it. When I check in debug, the ArrayBuffer is NOT detached. Clearly, something is breaking the inheritance at some point.

The only way that I can think to fix this, since I don't know where the inheritance breaks, is to provide a buffer of my own class which extends ArrayBuffer and overrides `instanceof`

[Based on this example from inheritance docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance)

```
class Float32ArrayBuffer extends ArrayBuffer {
    static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance: any) {
        var regularCheck = this instanceof instance;
        console.log('asdffdsa')
        console.log(instance)
        return regularCheck; 
    }
}
```

But that function never runs. I put a breakpoint before `instanceof` is run, and it is correctly my type. I'm not sure if there's another way I can go about overriding this, or if I can fix the root issue somehow. Any help is really appreciated, thanks

Comment: it looks like the documentation i linked is showing that `x instanceof MyType` is how this function is supposed to work. but I need to override the check for `MyType instanceof ArrayBuffer`

Comment: No, you are likely barking up the wrong tree. Please post a minimum reproducible example. `new (class extends ArrayBuffer {}) instanceof ArrayBuffer` returns `true` in my browser console.

Comment: Yes, a [mre] is what we need.  If I run your code then I can see the function indeed runs [see here](https://tsplay.dev/WGXMvw) so your problem cannot be reproduced.  (also, what do you expect `this instanceof instance` to do? Unless `instance` is a class constructor then that will give you a runtime error)

Comment: @jcalz, i do see why I couldnt get the function to run: because I was expecting the instanceof operator to behave backwards of how it needs to for the function to get hit.

Comment: @JaredSmith I cannot provide a minimum reproducible example because everything works as expected until my code runs through these third party libraries. I dont know what kind of transformations are applied to the data between my creation of the object and when it gets `instanceof ArrayBuffer` called against it :/. Everything in the debug view looks perfect: the prototypes match....when I call `e.buffer.prototype.constructor.toString() == ArrayBuffer.prototype.constructor.toString()`, it returns true. but then `e.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer` == false

Comment: Just post enough of your code so that somebody who has three.js can run it and see the error.

Comment: @JaredSmith I would if i could. but thanks for the help to both of you

Comment: Would you be so kind to at least name these third party libraries?

Comment: @pailhead Yeah, I'm using Matterport's SDK. I've further determined that when I call `new THREE.BufferGeometry()` it's returning a perfectly otherwise useable object but it fails even when trying `new THREE.BufferGeometry() instanceof Object`. I've since submitted a ticket with Matterport, I'm not sure if it's directly their issue but my only suspicion is that it has to be from their bundle. Because im not actually calling `new THREE._` but `new this.context.three._` where `context` is a MP object...i think. or at least i hope. sorry for the longwinded comment

Comment: It is possible that their sdk is importing a different version of three, in which case these checks could fail. This may not necessarily be an issue on their part, it could be your setup that is doing something unexpected with dependencies.

Comment: I glanced at npm and didn't find the library that actually uses all these objects, i just found something very terse, regarding some api keys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your application from within [NW.js](https://nwjs.io)? NW.js has a weird way of dealing with object contexts in mixed Node / V8 situations, where `myValue instanceof myConstructor` [can actually incorrectly return false](https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/#problem-with-instanceof). I've had Three.js GLTF loaders fail because of this.

A [possible solution](https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/#global-objects-in-mixed-context) to this is to enable `"chromium-args": "--mixed-context"` in your `package.json` file, which solved the problem for me. This makes [variable sharing](https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/#comparing-with-separate-context) harder, but I can't say that's caused me any grief.